# FullCalendar 5 - How do I get the end date of an event series - eventClick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am using FullCalendar 5 and JSON to populate the events:

```
id;
title;
daysOfWeek;
startRecur;
endRecur;
startTime;
endTime;
backgroundColor;
```

I have a series of Events with a start and end date. When I click on an Event the end date is showing as the date cell the Event occurrence is in. I want to retrieve the end date of the series of Events. I am using info.event.end.

This is the code:

```
eventClick: function(info) {
    var eventObj = info.event;
            
    $('#updateDescription').val(eventObj.title);
    $('#updateStartDate').val(moment(eventObj.start).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
    $('#updateEndDate').val(moment(eventObj.end).format('DD/MM/YYYY')); //Shows as 29/11/2021 should be 01/12/2021
    $('#updateStartTime').val(moment(eventObj.start).format('HH:mm'));
    $('#updateEndTime').val(moment(eventObj.end).format('HH:mm'));
    $('#updateColour').val(eventObj.backgroundColor);
            
    $('#ecClickModal').modal('show');
},

id: '001,
title: 'Event A',
daysOfWeek: '[1, 4]',
startRecur: '2021-01-01',
endRecur: '2022-12-30',
startTime: '10:00',
endTime: '11:00',
backgroundColor: 'Red',

id: '002,
title: 'Event B',
daysOfWeek: '[2, 3]',
startRecur: '2021-05-01',
endRecur: '2023-05-30',
startTime: '09:00',
endTime: '10:00',
backgroundColor: 'Blue',

id: '003,
title: 'Event C',
daysOfWeek: '[5]',
startRecur: '2020-01-01',
endRecur: null,
startTime: '10:00',
endTime: '11:00',
backgroundColor: 'Green',
```

When I click on 'Event B' I want to get the end date '2023-05-30'.

Currently, if I click on the occurrence of 'Event B' on '30/11/2021' then:

```
info.event.start is 30/11/2021
info.event.end is 30/11/2021
```

Recurring Events do not need an end date. So the solution must be able to cater for 'Event C' (i.e., a null end date please).

Comment: There's no way of doing this from an individual event, unfortunately. Maybe raise a feature request with the fullCalendar project (see https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features).

Comment: @ADyson I have raised a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are no in built functions in FullCalendar to fetch the last date from a series of events. You will have to fetch all events using [calendar::getEvents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEvents) and then find the end date of the last event.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    events: [
      {
        id: 'a',
        title: 'my event a',
        start: '2021-11-01',
        end: '2021-11-02'
      },
      {
        id: 'b',
        title: 'my event b',
        start: '2021-11-03',
        end: '2021-11-04'
      },
      {
        id: 'c',
        title: 'my event c ',
        start: '2021-11-05',
        end: '2021-11-06'
      },
      {
        id: 'd',
        title: 'my event d',
        start: '2021-11-07',
        end: '2021-11-08'
      },
    ],
  });

  calendar.render();

  // Fetching all events
  const allEvents = calendar.getEvents();


  // Sorting the events based on the last date (descending)
  allEvents.sort((eventA, eventB)=> {
    return eventB.end-eventA.end;
  });

  const lastDate = allEvents[0].end;
});
```

info.event.end only gives you the end date of a single event.

> Also, before I stumble into it, how do I manage a null end date please?

Could you please explain the issue?

Comment: Thank you for your help, very much appreciated. I have update the question to make it clearer. I want to get the end date of the recurring Event that I click on.